# Semantic Logging Exception: Keywords values larger than 0x0000100000000000 are reserved for system use

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, semantic-logging

I am using the Semantic Logging for my ASP.NET MVC app. https://github.com/mspnp/semantic-logging (SQL database) installed via nuget

```
Install-Package EnterpriseLibrary.SemanticLogging.Database
```

Here is the code that throws the exception.

```
var blockEventListener = new ObservableEventListener();
blockEventListener.EnableEvents(SemanticLoggingEventSource.Log, EventLevel.LogAlways, Keywords.All);
```

In my development platform using IIS Express, I don't have any exception but when I uploaded it to IIS 8.0 I got the following exception.

```
[ArgumentException: Keywords values larger than 0x0000100000000000 are reserved for system use]   
System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.CreateManifestAndDescriptors(Type eventSourceType, String eventSourceDllName, EventSource source) +14523758
System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.EnsureInitialized() +103
System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.SendCommand(EventListener listener, Int32 perEventSourceSessionId, Int32 etwSessionId, EventCommand command, Boolean enable, EventLevel level, EventKeywords matchAnyKeyword, IDictionary`2 commandArguments) +6352938
System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventListener.EnableEvents(EventSource eventSource, EventLevel level, EventKeywords matchAnyKeyword) +71
```